# How to output random data from CSV in php?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file with 100 rows but want to output 5 of them at random like $data[0][1][2][3] and $data[2][2][3]

I got it to show but it shows in a group

```
<?php 
 $row = 1;
 if (($handle = fopen("Book1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);

       $row++;
       for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
       }
      }
   fclose($handle);
 }
?>
```

Would like it to look like:

```
some data:<?php echo $data[0][1][2][3];?>
more data:<?php echo $data[1][1][2][3];?>
more data:<?php echo $data[5][1][2][3];?>
more data:<?php echo $data[8][1][2][3];?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [load the file into an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), it's easy enough to come up with a list of ["random" numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php), pull the corresponding line out, and use [`str_getcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) the same way you used `fgetcsv` in your code. It isn't the most efficient way to do it, as you need to read the whole file into memory. But it's necessary to determine the number of lines before choosing your random number.

```
<?php 
$rows = file("Book1.csv");
$len = count($rows);
$rand = [];
while (count($rand) < 5) {
    $r = rand(0, $len);
    if (!in_array($r, $rand)) {
        $rand[] = $r;
    }
}
foreach ($rand as $r) {
    $csv = $rows[$r];
    $data = str_getcsv($csv);
    // now do whatever you want with $data, which is one random row of your CSV
    echo "first column from row $r: $data[0]\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but what if I want to output each element separately and not joint

Comment: I'm not following. You have the data from each row in an array, you can do whatever you want with it.